# Звуковое сопровождение в notification android

Tags: android

Есть приложение, где появляется `notification`, когда приходят специальные сообщения. Пытаюсь при появлении уведомления воспроизводить свой аудиофайл, но ничего не происходит. 
В момент прихода спец. сообщения, срабатывает стандартный звук прихода SMS-сообщения. 
Есть подозрение, что notification запускается в основном потоке, таким образом моя звуковая дорожка не запускается, хотя она по времени длиннее стандартного SMS уведомления.
Вот код:

```
  Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);


        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Resources res = context.getResources();
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notify_icon)                    
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.notify_icon))
                .setTicker("Получено сообщение от информатора!")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(ringURI)
                .setContentTitle("Сообщение")
                .setContentText("Получено новое сообщение от информатора"); 


        Notification notification = builder.build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
```

Путь к файлу:

```
   Uri ringURI = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.mytest.app/raw/dewdrops2");
```

**UPDATE:** вывел notification в отдельном потоке, при поступлении SMS, заиграла моя аудиозапись примерно пол секунды(а её длина около 10 секунды), но потом заиграло стандартное уведомление (длина около 1 сек) и моя аудиозапись перестала воспроизводиться. В чём может быть проблема и как это решить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, стандартное звуковое уведомление о приходе СМС блокирует звуковое уведомление из кастомного notification. Решением стало выводить notification в отдельном потоке и усыплять его на 2 секунды, пока не отыграет стандартное уведомление и после этого запускать моё.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю что у вас файл не находит, поэтому воспроизводит стандартный рингтон. Попробуйте написать `Uri` так: `Uri.parse("android.resource://"+context.getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.FILE_NAME)`

Comment: Путь верный, проблема в другом, я обновил вопрос